# If read() method of FileInputStream return 1 byte and char in java occupy 2 bytes, how below program works

Tags: java, file, file-io

If `read()` method of `FileInputStream` return one byte and `char` in java occupy 2 bytes, how does casting of integer return by `read()` to `char` return character. Below is the program

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class ReadFile {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File file = new File("J:\\Java\\Programs\\xanadu.txt");
    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
    int i, iteration = 0;
    while ((i = stream.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.print((char) i);
        iteration++;
    }
    System.out.println("\nNo of Iteration :" + iteration);
  }
}
```

Content of file is : StackOverFlow

Output is :
StackOverflow
No of Iteration :13

So file contains 13 character which means 26 bytes. How the number of iteration is 13.

If there is a link where this behaviour is explain, please share it.

Comment: Is the file ASCII encoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file contains 13 ascii characters (and 1 ascii character is 1 byte). When stored in memory, in Java, each character might consumes 2 bytes. However, they are all on the basic plane... and they could be stored as UTF-8. While a single Java character might take 2 bytes of memory it might also take more when to create a single character when it's part of a `String` containing values from the [Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane).